# Using the Google Photos API to download photos and videos to my device?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-photos, google-photos-api

My iPhone has enough storage to download my entire Google Photos library, but there's no option in the Google Photos App to do this.

I'm learning Flutter app development, so I'm considering writing an app with a nice UI to facilitate this.

Does the Google Photos API have a method of downloading a photo and storing it in the local phone photo library? Would this be breaking any of the API rules? Would I run into API rate limits?

Comment: Hello David... Did you went in depth about it ? I have a similar need, and I want to know if I can access the photo collection trough api

Comment: Nope, didn’t investigate any further

Comment: Ok, thanks. Fyi, this is the link for my own question, with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707523/use-the-google-photos-library-api-from-a-kotlin-based-android-project-app?noredirect=1#comment99985348_56707523